# The Type Class (in app_Code) exists in both "solution.dll" and "app_code.wxdafd.dll"

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I have made one webapplication in C#.net and make a app_code folder where one file in created

named "SessionHelper.cs" (property set correctly to  "Compile" so that it can access in Webapplication)

it uses to set and get session parametes, when I try to debug it, gives me "Value" as below in "Watch window"

```
app_code.SessionHelper.IsURLCheckSupport(Name)

    The type 'Solution.Web.app_code.SessionHelper' exists in both 
'Solution.Web.dll' and 'App_Code.wgj24okr.dll'  (value)
```

See below,

[image]

So i am not able to get the value while debug it, what can be the solution for this.

Please let me know, if you want more details.

Comment: Silly question, but you wouldn't happen to have your build configuration set to Release instead of Debug, would you?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your temporary ASP.NET files?

Comment: Tried in both "DEBUG" and "Release" both mode before posting question

Comment: Yes, i tried to clear all the files from temp folder.

Comment: In my case, masterpage had the same class name. Changed it and sorted!

Answer (score 47):

This is occuring because your project is a "Web Application", when you Compile in Visual Studio, all the code in your site (including in `App_Code`) gets compiled into an assembly called, in this instance, `Solution.Web.dll`. When you run your site, asp.net knows about a "special" folder called `App_Code` and compiles the content of it into an assembly with a unique name, in this instance `App_Code.wgj24okr.dll'.

One solution is to rename your `App_Code` folder to another name, such as `Code`.

Comment: +1 That one should be accepted in this case, as it really fixes this issue. Thx a lot for it. BTW, so what does the special folder App_Code in this case? Can it be used for something?

Comment: ***Not use special folder App_Code*** is the _solution_ ? What's about in VB.NET, not found class if change the name to ***App_Code*** ?