# The Type Class (app_Code class) exists in both “solution.dll” and “App_Code.lfoxsb3d.dll'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on asp.net 4.0 web project, when I run it I got the error message

> The type 'myproject.MyClass' exists in both
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\d76f4ecb\381a37f3\assembly\dl3\824d7fec\6a842c0e_ad7bce01\myproject.DLL'
>   and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\d76f4ecb\381a37f3\App_Code.lfoxsb3d.dll'

MyClass.cs resides in App_Code folder
I tried cleaning ASP.net temporary folder,cleaning the solution, resetting IIS, but no luck, I found one solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190014/the-type-class-in-app-code-exists-in-both-solution-dll-and-app-code-wxdafd) so I tried with renaming App_Code,it runs fine after renaming,but when I login to my application,It gave exception

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.masterpage_master' to type 'myproject.MasterPage'
```

on this line

```
((MasterPage)Master).PageSection = "Accountant";
```

I undid renaming the App_Code(as its not solution to my problem)
How can I fix this type exists error?
I am using Telerik.Web.UI  v4.0.30319

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because your project is a "Web Application", when you Compile in Visual Studio, all the code in your site (including in App_Code) gets compiled into an assembly called, in this instance, MyProject.dll. When you run your site, asp.net knows about a "special" folder called App_Code and compiles the content of it into an assembly with a unique name, in this instance `App_Code.xxxxxxxxx.dll'.

One solution is to rename your App_Code folder to another name, such as BusinessLogic.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a new folder and put all of your app_code files in that folder.